# How do i pass long file names to the Cyberduck CLI in windows?

Tags: cyberduck

I am trying to upload a file using Windows 7 and the Cyberduck CLI.

duck --upload "b2://api.backblace.com/Account/FileName, with a comma and a space.txt" "FileName, with a comma and a space.txt" --username XXXXX --password XXXXX

Yields:

File not found. C:\Users\User/FileName, with a comma and a space.txt. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.

Files with no spaces or comma's in them upload just fine... I tried ^'s /'s, and extra "'s to escape the file names, but I just can't figure out how to pass a file name with spaces and commas so the CLI finds it?

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the filename in the b2 URL that you pass? E.g. b2://api.backblace.com/Account/FileName,%20with%20a%20comma%20and%20a%20space.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ManoDestra hit the nail on the head!

The error message was saying the c:\ file was not found so I thought it was a problem with the local file.  It was really just an unclear error message from cyberDuck, and url encoding the upload url indeed solved the problem.

duck --upload "b2://api.backblaze.com/Account/FileName,%20with%20a%20comma%20and%20a space.txt" "FileName, with a comma and a space.txt" --username XXXXX --password XXXXX

Worked like a charm!